# How can you open a file that the user specifies on the command line?

Tags: c++

Suppose you want to allow the user to specify a file to open on the command line. How can this be achieved if the user will enter data such as:

/User/desktop/input.txt

How can I then convert this directory into something that the program actually opens/reads?

Comment: Y do you need the file name alone? The whole path is needed to open that particular file..

Comment: Why would you need to split the path ? If you use just the filename and not the path how will you guarantee you know the directory ?

Comment: That's correct. I will modify my original question.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what do you mean by 'specifies on the command line'. Did you just mentioned command line, because you're building a console application or do you want to pass the filename/path on command-line to your program?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `argc` holds the count of command line arguments. If you don't pass any arguments, it's 1 (`argv[0]` is just the name of your executable). Otherwise its the count of command line arguments + 1.

```
#include <fstream>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
  if(argc>1){
    std::ifstream a(argv[1]); // first argument
    if(a){
      //file opened
    }
  }
}
```

To start this program, you would type on your command-line:

```
nameOfYourExecutable.exe /User/desktop/input.txt
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean) for further informations.

Answer (score 1):

[std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) is the way.

```
std::ifstream file(your_file_path);

if (!file) { return; } // check the file 

std::string line;
while (getline(file, line)) { /* do some process on line */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `open("path",permissions,flags)` will work fine.. and you can read or write using the file descriptor.

Comment: @user3064097: as simple as it is

Answer (score 0):

What is the deference if you get it from the command line argument, or hard-code it in your program?
just use open().